# «Будет и седой» — кто?

Tags: смысл, поэзия

Немного не понял смысл этих строчек в стихотворении Бальмонта «Золотое слово»:

*Там, где не достала, — лютик золотой,

Жёлтый одуванчик, — будет и седой.*

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что имел в виду автор, описывая этими словами Весну?
Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Седым будет одуванчик, когда желтые цветки в его корзинке станут семенами с бело-серыми хохолками.

А что касается Весны, то предыдущее четверостишие описывает в основном действия реки:

*Солнце золотится. Лютик — золотой.

Речка серебрится и шалит водой.

Родилась на воле, залила луга,

Затопила поле, стёрла берега.*

О реке говорится и дальше: где она не достала своими водами, там лютики и одуванчики.